# PowerShell NEW-ADUsers script - passing variable with stored parameters and arguments to new-aduser cmd

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I would appreciate some help. I am trying to create a universal scrip to import user depending on csv that has been exported and the selecting only the columns that is needed to import new users into AD. I just cannot get New-ADUser $syntax to take work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        function importModuleActiveDirectory(){
            Try
                {
                  Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
                }
            Catch
                {
                  Write-Host "[ERROR]`t ActiveDirectory Module couldn't be loaded. Script will stop!"
                  Exit 1
                }   
        }
        $csvDirPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
        $csvFile    = $csvDirPath + "\users.csv"
        $adDomain   = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
        $adOu       = 'CN=Users,' + $adDomain
        $usersCsv   = Import-Csv "$csvFile" 

        function createUsers{
            $newUsers=@()
            $existingUsers=@()
            $usersCsv |ForEach{      

                try{

                    Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName
                    $newUsers += $SamAccountName
                }
                catch{$existingUsers += $SamAccountName}
            }

            if($newUsers.Count -ne $userCsv.count){
                echo "Please check the above users that do exist on the Domain!"
                $existingUsers| ForEach-Object{
                    echo $_
                }    
            }
            else{
                ForEach($userObj in $usersCsv){
                    $getProperties = Get-Member -InputObject $userObj -MemberType NoteProperty            
                    $syntax

                    ForEach($p in $getProperties){
                        $properties = $p.Name

                        foreach($property in $properties){ 

                            if($userObj.$property -ne $null){

                                if($property -eq "accountpassword"){


                                    $syntax += ' -'+$property+' (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText '+$userObj.$property+' -Force)'
                                }
                                else{

                                        $syntax += ' -'+$property+' "'+ $userObj.$property+'"'

                                }
                            }        
                        }             
                    }
                    try{

                        New-ADUser $syntax

                    }
                    catch [Exception]{
                        write-host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName; 
                        write-host $_.Exception.Message; 
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        createUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working way to hard here. New-ADUser is designed to work with situations like this one. In other words, you should:

```
Import-Csv YourFile | New-ADUser
```

For AccountPassword - you can probably get it working using `Select-Object` and convert string to SecureString there.

```
Import-Csv YourFile | Select-Object *, @{ 
    Name = 'AccountPassword'
    Expression = { ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlain -Force $_.AccountPassword }
} -Exclude AccountPassword | New-ADUser
```

But: if you want to continue like that you should use splatting, rather than try to build string that looks like command. And Invoke-Expression something you only partially control is just asking for trouble (code injection anybody?).

Answer (score 0):

I am a new at PowerShell however I have had some practice with other languages. I was not able to use the Invoke-expression. However after my question I thought that it seems that when importing the CSV that it puts the lines into objects so the I asked myself instead of creating the syntax string can I not add the object as a AD User object directly. And what do you know there you go. So please find new code below and thanks for looking at it.

```
            function importModuleActiveDirectory(){
                Try
                    {
                        Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
                    }
                Catch
                    {
                        Write-Host "[ERROR]`t ActiveDirectory Module couldn't be loaded. Script will stop!"
                        Exit 1
                    }   
            }

            importModuleActiveDirectory

            #Static Variables. Do not change

            $getDir = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
            $directoryPath = $getDir+"\"
            $logDirectoryPath = $directoryPath+"NewADUserslog\"+(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd.HHmmss)
            $adDomain   = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
            $existingUsers=@()
            $logFile = $logDirectoryPath+"\Error.log"
            $errorsArray =@()
            $rectifyUsersCsv = $logDirectoryPath+"\RectifyUsers.csv"

            #Configure variables

            $csvFile    = $directoryPath + "users.csv" #set csv name




            #Import CSV as Object and reate Users

            $usersCsv   = Import-Csv $csvFile

            foreach($user in $UsersCsv){

                try{
                    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName
                    $existingUsers += $user.SamAccountName
                }
                catch{}
                if($existingUsers.Count -eq 0){
                    try{
                        $user.accountpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $user.accountpassword -Force
                        $user|New-ADUser
                    }
                    catch [Exception]{
                        New-Item $logDirectoryPath -ItemType directory
                        $err = New-Object PSObject
                        Add-Member -InputObject $err -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DateTime -Value (Get-Date -Format s)
                        Add-Member -InputObject $err -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SamAccountUser -Value $user.SamAccountName
                        Add-Member -InputObject $err -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Error -Value $_
                        $err|Export-Csv -Append -Path $logFile -NoTypeInformation
                        $errorsArray += $err
                        echo $err
                        $user|Export-Csv -Append -Path $rectifyUsersCsv -NoTypeInformation
                    }    
                }
                else{
                    foreach($u in $existingUsers){
                        echo $u
                    }
                    echo "The Above users already exist! Please rectify before importing."
                }
                if($errorsArray.Count -ne 0){



                }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Expression "New-ADUser $syntax"
```

The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates a string as a command.